# When use addorg3.sh , I can not add org3 into channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[image]

when I copy the file into addorg3
[image]

then work again
[image]

please help me make this work

thanks!

Comment: It looks like the addOrg3.sh script is currently broken by a recent change to fabric-samples main branch.
You could use `git checkout b50611575b4acbe9efac768b4ff44426a5809375` to a commit level before the change that should work

Comment: The issue should now be fixed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.